# How to implement a ip white list secured spring integration http inbound gateway?

Tags: http, filter, spring-integration, whitelist

We want to add a white list on a spring integration http inbound gateway. I have googled for quite a while but found few useful. Is there some out-of-box filter in spring integration can do this？ like:

```
<int-http:inbound-gateway request-channel="toOutbound" path="/proxy/someService" >
    <int:filter expression="hasIpAddress(www.somepartner.com, www.otherpartner.com)"/>
</int-http>
```

Or how can we get the request ip address in the message header and implement a custom filter.

Any idea is welcome, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The http gateway currently runs within a servlet container (tomcat etc); you can either use the native container's security features, or use the Spring Security project to secure your application (the DispatcherServlet) independent of the server implementation.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, Gary. We're currently using the Spring HandlerInterceptor to implement this. So is this a recommended implementation strategy?

Comment: Yes; there are some tricks you can use to get a reference to the servlet request in SI components (such as a filter), but it's probably easier to deal with it in the web context, before we even hit SI.